# How to end the Page Load Event and load after that?

Tags: pages

I have been doing a lot of research on fast page load (initial load), and I have been seeing references to a technique where you get the most important content down, then end the Page Load Event (so that is what search calculates), then you load some more things afterwards.

But I cannot find the procedure. What is the code or examples to end the page load event, and how do I put things on the page after that?

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks, Justin

Comment: You could use lazy loading technique. There are number of lazy loading plugins available in WP. e.g. Lazy Load XT

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer to avoid plugins, but don't mind using some javascript like Lazy Load on the Theme. How does it work though? Where in the page code does it tell the browser that the page load event has concluded, and then how do you keep loading to it?

Comment: Use of jQuery library is better option. You may refer [this](https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/) link and [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) link for code examples and demo.